# How to query the the fields of a specific column of a MySQL table as their own column (same ones grouped)

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table,

```
|| name      | tag       ||
||-----------|-----------||
|| Lennart   | tag1      ||
|| Lennart   | tag3      ||
|| Lennart   | tag4      ||
|| John      | tag2      ||
|| John      | tag3      ||
|| Pete      | tag3      ||
|| Pete      | tag4      ||
|| Lucas     | tag2      ||
```

of which I need to query something like this:

```
|| tag1    | tag2    | tag3    | tag4    ||
||---------|---------|---------|---------||
|| Lennart | John    | Lennart | Lennart ||
||         | Lucas   | John    | Pete    ||
||         |         | Pete    |         ||
```

In other words: I need to query the tags inside the table as own columns. In these columns I need the matching names of course.

Would that even be possible at all in a single MySQL query?

Greets, Lennart

Comment: How are the names related that causes them to be on the same row of the result?

Comment: This seems similar to a pivot, but there's no key column to relate all the columns in each row.

Comment: They are not related by any way. The row totaly doesn't matter, I just need the names to be in the column which is given by the tag. It's really hard for me to explain, because I'm not a native English-speaker... @Barmar

Comment: This is not easy to do in MySQL. If you're querying from a scripting language like PHP or Python, it will be easy to do in a loop there.

Comment: I think that I'll just create an multi-dimensional array or so in PHP. It would be nicer to simply change out the query, because then I wouldn't have to change some other parts of the script, but sadly, like I expected, this won't be that easy in just a single MySQL query. But thanks anyway ^^

Comment: It is *possible* in MySQL, but so tedious that I wouldn't bother. Save this kind of thing for application level code